# Change SAS 9.0 Default Encoding to UTF-8

Tags: encoding, utf-8, sas, default

1. The default encoding that was set on it earlier was "waltin1".

Now since I wanted SAS to create all the dataset in "UTF-8" automatically, I had added ENCODING="UTF-8" in the config(.cfg) file. Post that, though the default encoding got changed to "UTF-8", which I verfired by running PROC OPTIONS; OPTION = ENCODING=QUIT; , it still creates all the datasets in "wlatin1".

Interstingly, when I set ENCODING = "USCI-II" (just for testing), it did create all the data sets in "usci-ii".

Any idea why this different behavior towards the 2 encoding values and how to fix this?

Comment: I strongly suggest moving off of SAS 9.0.  It was not a very stable release and was followed up within a few months by SAS 9.1.3, which has much better support for UTF-8.  Your site should look into doing so as soon as possible.  SAS 9.3+ have even better support, if you can upgrade to that.

Comment: In the meanwhile, is there a 'u8' folder in [SASHOME]\nls\ ?  What is there (does nls even exist as a folder in 9.0)?